# Hibernate onetomany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to map a relation for the first time. I have found a lot of ways to go.

There are two classes: 
- Project (Parent)
- Application (Child)

So one project can have several applications, but one application belongs to just one project..

I constructed them as follows:

**Project.java**

```
 import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    @Entity
    public class Project {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable=false)
        @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name = "project_index")
        List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>();

        [get and set methods...]
        }
```

**Application.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

    @Entity
    public class Application {

         @Id
         @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         private int id;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)
            private Project project;

        [get and set methods...]
     }
```

...but, unfortunately I got an exception I can not deal with:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ....common.entities.Application._applicationsBackref
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
 org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
 org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
 org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:343)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:83)

root cause

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ....common.entities.Application._applicationsBackref
 javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
 com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
 javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
 org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
 org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
 org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:343)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
 org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:83)

root cause

org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: ....common.entities.Application._applicationsBackref
 org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:95)
 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:313)
 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
```

Where is my mistake? I mean there is nothing null. Only on project side

---

When I remove @JoinColumn on owning side an exception occures:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'project_id' doesn't have a default value
```

---

Thank you Pascal

Comment: Can you show us what are you trying to put to database when this exception occures? How are you creating Application and Project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are several things to fix in your mapping.

- Your association is bidirectional, you need to use the `mappedBy` attribute on the "One" side (or what you'll get is two unidirectional associations) to define the field that "owns" the relation on the owning side (the side that holds the foreign key i.e. the Many side in a one-to-many).
- The `@JoinColumn` annotation should be defined on the owning side only, not both sides.
- If you are using a JPA 2.0 compliant version of Hibernate (i.e. Hibernate 3.5+), prefer the standard `@OrderColumn` annotation of the Hibernate specific `@IndexColumn`
- I'm not sure to understand why you defined the `@JoinColumn` as totally read-only with `updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false`, this doesn't sound appropriate.

So your mappings become (assuming you're using JPA 2.0):

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="project")
    @OrderColumn(name = "project_index")
    List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>();

    // getters, setters
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

    // getters, setters
 }
```

And since your association, is bidirectional, don't forget to set both sides of the link when creating your object graph:

```
Project p = new Project();
Application a = new Application();
a.setProject(p);
p.getApplications().add(a);
em.persist(p);
```

But I would actually recommend to create link management methods in your entities to set both sides of the link, e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    ...
    public void addToApplications(Application app) {
        this.applications.add(app);
        app.setProject(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Resources

- Hibernate Core Documentation

  - [1.2.6. Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-bidirectional)
- JPA wiki book

  - [Example of a OneToMany relationship and inverse ManyToOne annotations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_and_inverse_ManyToOne_annotations)

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 2.1.8.2 "Bidirectional ManyToOne / OneToMany Relationships"
  - Section 9.1.24 "OneToMany Annotation"
  - Section 9.1.22 "ManyToOne Annotation"
- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 11.1.39 "OrderColumn Annotation"

Comment: One thing: List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>();....that list should not be initialized or else the list gonna be empty after query... I had hibernate to initialize it!!!

Comment: @Sven Hmm... No, this is not true. There must be something else.

Comment: @Pascal why should this be bi-directional rather than uni-directional? How would the implementation change?

Answer (score 4):

`@JoinColumn` annotation is not needed on both sides. In fact, you should only put this on owning side of the relationship.

Moreover, you have describe the thing as below,

`@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)`

Its totally making no sense. This, acutally, means that you don't want to update it, neither you like to insert it, nor you want it null.

Furthermore, you are missing `@Column` annotation upon your `Id` fields, in case the name of the actual column is not `id`.

Comment: when you say owning side, do you mean parent side? that's not clear to me

Comment: @Sven: Owning-side is the one which owns the foreign key. So, the entity for the table having foreign-key should be the owning-side. In your case it would be `Application`.

Comment: @Sven: Did I suggest you to remove it from the owning side? I think I said to keep it only there. :)

Answer (score -1):

Entity

```
@Table(name="Customer_v1")

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

public class Customer implements Serializable{                

                @Id

                @Column(name="cust_id")

                protected int custId;

 ------------------------------------------------

@Entity

@DiscriminatorValue(value = "N")

public class NewCustomer extends Customer {}

 

@Entity

@DiscriminatorValue( value="E")

public class ExistingCustomer extends Customer{}
```