# Mapping a one to many relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables, a `user` table and a `user_avatar` table. For each user, there are 3 records in the `user_avatar` table, for 3 sizes of avatars (large, medium, small).

The `user_avatar` table has a `userId` column which refers to the `User.id` field to specify to which user an avatar belongs to.

Here's my `UserAvatar` class:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "user_avatar")

public class UserAvatar
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AvatarSize size;

    private String file;
    private String s3Key;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return size + " " + file;
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm referring to it in the `user

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OrderColumn(name = "id")
    public UserAvatar[] avatar; //declared array as there'd be at least 3 records
}
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

```
Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.xxx.User.avatar column: id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657197/hibernate-onetomany-mapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here is a `bidrectional many-to-one`, where you want to populate objects on both sides of the relationship.

Hibernate will complain if you have a `JoinColumn` on both sides, so just put it on the "owning" side and add `mappedBy` to the other side.

See this example:

```
public class UserAvatar {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId") // userId is the name of your database FK column
    private User user;

    ...
}

public class User {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    public List<UserAvatar> avatars;

    ...
}
```

As for the particular error you were getting, I believe that was caused by `JoinColumn("id")` in `User` conflicting with the primary key column `id`.

Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512565/1747491).

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will maintain an association's order when you use a `List` or an array. To do that, it needs an integer column in the many-side table to store the record's position in the `List`/array. You can either:

1. Change your field to use a `Set`, for which Hibernate will not attempt to maintain ordering.
2. Add an integer type column to your database to store the record order, and name that in the `@OrderColumn` annotation.

Comment: Looks like it to me, at least according to your description.

Comment: I changed `UserAvatar[]` to `Set<UserAvatar>`, and now I get this: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.xxx.User.avatar references an unknown entity: java.util.Set`

Comment: You need to map both sides.  `@ManyToOne` goes on the One side, `@OneToMany` goes on the collection side.

Comment: I would highly recommend working through a tutorial before going any further.

Comment: I'm now getting `Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.xxx.User.avatar column: id` after my last edit. Totaly stumped on what I'm doing wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48507/discussion-between-peter-bratton-and-click-upvote)